# Issue with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, storyboard

I want to use storyboard in my old project (which was implemented using xibs) for adding a new features.

I have created storyboard file and added a view controller to it and in Identity inspector I have specified the class name for the view controller.

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES
}


@end
```

In the firstviewcontroller when i click on a button it will call the gotoSomeviewController method where it pushes to the eventslistViewController loading from EventsScreen storyboard

@implementation FirstViewController

```
-(void)gotoSomeviewController
{
    EventsListViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EventsScreen" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

[controller pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }

@end

when I'm running application the EventsListViewController is showing a empty screen without the views I have added in storyboard.

Comment: I think more information is needed before someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @lindonfox Please let me know what details needed
.

Comment: Your missing a load of information here. Start by explaining what you are completing in the App Delegate to load the storyboard to the window, if you have any code there. From the above it looks like you are loading a ViewController as a Storyboard, so it doesnt make much sense

Comment: @StuartM Im not loading anything in app delegate… I have edited the code

Comment: Your question is weak. You need to explain what you are trying to achieve and what has been completed. I do not understand your code example you have a method in the interface file, what is that for? How is the storyboard setup? You obviously load your initialviwcontroller without any code. Then what happens? How are you going to the next? provide more information we cannot guess

Comment: @StuartM please check i have added some more details

Comment: Start from the top. The initial view controller loads without any code in App Delegate. What is the code example in the question for? You are instantiating the initial view controller in this code, why? You should not need to it should already load. Where is the method in your example code actually called from?

Comment: @StuartM please check it .. I have added some more details

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information supplied there should be no reason why you mix NIBs and Storyboard.

I would setup just a storyboard. Remove the app Delegate code and setup the project to load the storyboard for the specific device.

Setup your storyboard to have the initial view controller as a `UINavigationController` that has the `FirstViewController` as the root of that.

Then you can simply drag to the `SecondViewController` from the button and select push as the move option. Then remove your method for gotoviewcontroller. There is no reason why you would have this setup like this...

Comment: there was no problem in mixing the xib's and storyboard files. The actual problem in my project was the base controller of my class in which the initwithcoder method was not calling the super. Thanks for the comments